# How I can scrape some data from web page

Tags: java, jsoup

I have problem with web scraping. What I want to do is this:

I have this site: https://www.arrentacar.rs/sr/vozni-park/#

As you can see on page button "Rezervisi" when I click on it, I would like to scrape next data:

First dropdown menu when site open new window, its "Volkswagen UP! 1.0" in that dropdown list I want to scrape all cars, then in this dropdown menu called "Mesto preuzimanja vozila" I want to scrape all items, and in dropdown menu called "Mesto vracanja vozila" I want to scrape all items.

This is how I tried for car names, in first dropdown menu:

```
Document doc
            = Jsoup.connect("https://www.arrentacar.rs/sr/vozni-park/#").get();

    Elements elems = doc.select(".inner-form__elements");

    for (Element e : elems) {
        String carName = e.select(".select-vehicle").text();
        System.out.println(carName);
    }
```

This works fine, but it wont show me data in table columns, while titles and ratings from IMDB show me correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors can be tweaked. Don't select by class when you can use specific id. Here you can because the `select` you want has unique name and id `<select name="car" id="carlist" ... >` so any of them will be a better choice.
This way you will also avoid `for` loop which is currently looping over only one element because there's only one element with class `inner-form__elements`.
Your second selector `.select-vehicle` is also too general and it selects too much. That way `text()` returns everything it contains as one string. To get only options you'd have to select all tags `option` which are inside `select` with `id` equal to `carlist`. Then you can iterate over them so you'll get single strings.
The code for first two dropdowns is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.arrentacar.rs/sr/vozni-park/#").get();

// selecting all "options" from element with id=carlist
Elements cars = doc.select("#carlist > option");

// remove "Izaberi vozilo"
cars.remove(cars.first());

// display all cars
for (Element car : cars) {
    System.out.println(car.text());
}

System.out.println("------");

// selecting all "options" from element with id=mestopreuzimanja
Elements startLocations = doc.select("#mestopreuzimanja > option");

// display locations
for (Element startLocation : startLocations) {
    System.out.println(startLocation.text());
}
```

Try to select values of the third dropdown (destination locations) the same way as I did with startLocations.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Are you still here because I have one more question?

Comment: Just ask. Sooner or later I'll be back.

Comment: Since I need to put this information in the spreadsheet, why won't some information be displayed to me? For example, it shows some data to me in the console but does not want to save it to my database and display it in a spreadsheet. I use Javafx tables

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about javafx. That deserves a separate question anyway. If you liked answer to this question remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).